# Python: encode special character

Tags: python, special-characters, encode

I'm trying to encode a string containing '-' (minus) symbol to iso8859-15, it will return the string as it is. 
 for eg:

```
str="abc-def"
```

Expected output is

```
abc%2Ddef
```

Is there any way to do this? sorry me if my question is wrong.

Comment: That is not Latin-1 encoding. You may want to brush up on what encodings *are*. :-)

Comment: Do not name a variable `str`; that masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output sample suggest you are looking for *url encoding*, not Latin-1.

The [`urllib.quote()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) and [`urllib.quote_plus()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) functions can be used to do such quoting, but the `-` character does **not** need quoting and won't be quoted:

> Replace special characters in *string* using the `%xx` escape. Letters, digits, and the characters `'_.-'` are never quoted.

Demo:

```
>>> from urllib import quote
>>> quote('abc-def')
'abc-def'
>>> quote('some data that needs quoting!')
'some%20data%20that%20needs%20quoting%21'
```

If you are using Python 3, the `quote` and `quote_plus` functions are found in the [`urllib.parse` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting).

Answer (score 1):

ya.

```
from urllib.parse import quote
st = "abc-def"
encoded = quote(st)
```

Comment: For the record, `urllib.parse` is a Python 3 module. In Python 2, `quote` is in `urllib` (no submodules).